# Strong Convergence of Finite Rank Operators to Bounded Operator: Is boundedness necessary?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space. It is an exercise in Stein and Shakarchi to show that such an operator can be approximated (strongly) by finite rank operators, the approach being to consider the sequence $(P_nT)$ where $P_n$ is the projection onto the span of the first $n$ elements of the basis. However, after proving this I do not think my proof makes use of the boundedness assumption.

It suffices to prove that $\|Q_nf\|$ ($Q_n$ being the projection onto the subspace spanned by the rest of the basis vectors) strongly converges to zero, and this follows by noting for
$f \sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_ke_k$
$$\|Q_nf\|^2 = \sum_{k > n}|a_k|^2 \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty$$
Then using the fact that $I = P_n + Q_n$ we can write $$\|P_nTf- Tf\| = \|Q_nTf\| \to 0 
\text{ as } n \to \infty$$ using strong convergence of $Q_n$.

Am I missing something or is the boundedness assumption only there because we "aren't interested" in the unbounded operators in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all unbounded operators is not usually seen as a topological space for various reasons.  For example strong
convergence $T_n\to T$ of *bounded operators* requires that
$$
  T_n(f)\to T(f),
  \tag 1
  $$
for every $f$ in the space.

In case of unbounded operators, each of which has its own domain, one would have to decide where to take the above $f$'s
from.  Should (1) be required only for $f$'s in the intersection of all domains?  In the rather common case in which
that intersection is empty, should the convergence then hold by default?

Alas, I believe  that attempts to introduce a topology on the set of all unbounded operators have not been
successful.

This said, I certainly agree that
$$
  P_nT(f)\to T(f),
  $$
for every $f$ in the domain of $T$, even though I believe this convergence  cannot be interpreted within a sensible topological space.

Comment: Thank you for these insights, that answers my question and helps give more context!